# Submit bug fix to Windows Store without going through the certification process every time

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I was wondering if there is a way to submit a bug fix to an app in the Windows Store without having the app go through the certification process every time.  I have an app in the store and every once in a while I have a small tweak that I need to make.  Having the app go through the certification process every time takes a considerable amount of time and once in a while it fails for some random reason.  I can resubmit it without any changes and it will pass.  The process doesn't seem consistent.

Comment: If the app is distributed through the Windows Store, then it will have to be recertified each time.  Your change may be small, but it's different than the previously approved version.  If no recertification was necessary, what would to prevent a malicious (or inexperienced) developer from making a change that causes problems for users or violates some requirements?  When you're submitting the same packages multiple times and it fails once, then passes the next, what are the reasons given for failure?

Comment: @daughtkom Is exactly right. To add to this, each time a package is created, it is re-signed with MSFT's keys, ensuring that all code run on a consumer's device came directly from Microsoft and no one else. This signature changes significantly even with a seemingly insignificant change to the package.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was just hoping there was a way to get small changes through.  For instance one of the things I failed on recently was on my group headers I had a date with a ">" next to it.  The tester must have thought that it was a button instead of static text because they failed me on it.  It passed three previous releases though.